# Calculation about ellipsoid and unit sphere are conformal

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry

$S^2$ is the topological sphere. Consider two differet metric on it, respectively denote $(S^2,g_1), (S^2, g_2)$. The two metric are conformally equivalent if
$$
g_1=\lambda g_2
$$
where $\lambda:S^2\rightarrow (0,+\infty)$.  Seemly, the [Uniformization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) imply that $(S^2,g_1)$ and $(S^2, g_2)$ are conformally equivalent. Therefore, I try some specific example.

The unit sphere in 3-dim Euclidean space
\begin{align}
&r(\theta,\varphi)=(\sin\theta\cos\varphi, \sin\theta\sin\varphi,\cos\theta)
\\
&r_\theta=(\cos\theta\cos\varphi,\cos\theta\sin\varphi,-\sin\theta)
\\
&r_\varphi=(-\sin\theta\sin\varphi, \sin\theta\cos\varphi, 0)
\end{align}
$$
g_1=\left(
\begin{array}{1}
1  &0  \\
0  &\sin^2\theta
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The ellipsoid in 3-dim Euclidean space
\begin{align}
&r(\theta,\varphi)=(\sin\theta\cos\varphi, \sin\theta\sin\varphi, 2\cos\theta)
\\
&r_\theta=(\cos\theta\cos\varphi,\cos\theta\sin\varphi,-2\sin\theta)
\\
&r_\varphi=(-\sin\theta\sin\varphi, \sin\theta\cos\varphi, 0)
\end{align}
$$
g_2=\left(
\begin{array}{1}
1+3\sin^2\theta  &0  \\
0  &\sin^2\theta
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Obviously, when $\sin\theta \ne 0$, there is not $\lambda$ such that $g_1=\lambda g_2$. How to understand it ?